# Getting Blank Lists - No Idea Why?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, enumerate

I use this code:

```
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

in_file = open("s:/Personal Folders/Andy/Python Projects/People Cancelled/Analyze Authorize Truncated.csv")
text = in_file.readlines()
in_file.close()

header = text[0:1]
text = text[1:]

for index, line in enumerate(text):
    text[index] = line.split(",")

name = text
dates = text

for index, line in enumerate(name):
    name[index] = line[3:5]

for stuff, area in enumerate(dates):
     dates[stuff] = area[7:8]

print(name)
print(dates)
```

And I get this output:

```
 [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
 [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Any idea why? For some reason there seems to be some sort of interference between the two of the for loops - if I do either individually I get the results I want.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us an example of your input data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at these two lines:

```
name = text
date = text
```

These lines do *not* make copies of text for name and date to point to; rather, they set both name and date to be in essence alternate names for text. So, after the third for loop (with body `name[index] = line[3:5]`, every line in `text` is two items long (because `text` and `name` are the same list). In fact, I don't even see why you set both `name` and `date` equal to `text` initially; the intended results could be achieved simply by making `name` and `date` equal to new, empty lists and appending items to them based on `text`.

Comment: Ah, doh, that makes sense! I'll have to figure out how to append to a new list values from an old list but that shouldn't be too hard.

Actually, I can also take a slice of text (i.e. text[:]) and it should work

Comment: Lists have a method `append` - seems like that should be perfect. Or, you could define new lists in terms of the old ones using list comprehensions, like `name = [line[3:5] for line in text]`